# Increase sensitivity of a touchpad with the synaptics driver

Tags: xorg, synaptics

What settings do I need to tweak in order to increase the sensitivity of my touchpad in synaptics?

```
$ synclient
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = -2393
    RightEdge               = 2651
    TopEdge                 = -2030
    BottomEdge              = 2139
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    FingerPress             = 256
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 346
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    FastTaps                = 0
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 100
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 157
    HorizScrollDelta        = 157
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0253743
    TrackstickSpeed         = 40
    EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
    EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
    EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
    EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 630
    EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
    UpDownScrolling         = 1
    LeftRightScrolling      = 1
    UpDownScrollRepeat      = 1
    LeftRightScrollRepeat   = 1
    ScrollButtonRepeat      = 100
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 0
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 4
    VertHysteresis          = 4
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 0
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 0
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

When I move my finger slowly, I have to swipe multiple times to get around the screen. When I swipe really quickly, it can easily span the whole display, but I'd like to increase the general sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe kind of makes sense, in other words, when moving slowly, the pointer also respods slowly, and when swiping quickly, the pointer gets accelerated. Obviously, if the intention is to move across the screen, you'd swipe quickly rather then slowly.

That said, if you wish to increase the pointer speed, bump up the `MinSpeed` and `AccelFactor` parameters.

For example: `synclient MinSpeed=1.2 AccelFactor=0.05`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for command line for a fact, but from your list I'd increase
AccelFactor a lot, and possibly MinSpeed and MaxSpeed if that didn't solve it.

If you have ubuntu, then System > Preferences > Mouse gives graphical editor for acceleration and sensitivity, or alternatively: https://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings

hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, the system preferences have never actually been useful at all, ever.